# How to Debug 'ip link add vrf-blue type vrf table 10' RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, routes

I am trying to enable vrf in Linux kernel 4.9.135 version and have enabled `IP_MULTIPLE_TABLES`, `NET_L3_MASTER_DEV` and `NET_VRF` in kernel and build the kernel.

```
bash-4.3# zgrep "CONFIG_NET_VRF" /proc/config.gz

  CONFIG_NET_VRF=m

bash-4.3# zgrep "IP_MULTIPLE_TABLES" /proc/config.gz

  CONFIG_IP_MULTIPLE_TABLES=y

bash-4.3# zgrep "NET_L3_MASTER_DEV" /proc/config.gz

  CONFIG_NET_L3_MASTER_DEV=y
```

I am using iproute2 version iproute2-4.9.0-r0.0.x86_64.rpm also which supports vrf.

But when I am trying to instantiate a VRF device and associate it with a table, I am getting RTNETLINK answers: operation not supported.

I checked through the strace and see RTNETLINK messages:

```
sendmsg(3, {msg_name(12)={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, msg_iov(1)=[{"H\0\0\0\20\0\5\6(\20\271\\\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 72}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 72

recvmsg(3, {msg_name(12)={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, msg_iov(1)=[{"\\\0\0\0\2\0\0\0(\20\271\\\302i\0\0\241\377\377\377H\0\0\0\20\0\5\6(\20\271\\"..., 32768}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 92
write(2, "RTNETLINK answers: Operation not"..., 43RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported
```

How to debug/resolve this problem?

Comment: Please show the relevant code. Please state where the error is encountered. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You need to probe the vrf kernel module

```
# modprobe vrf
```